# In R Shiny, isTruthy() function is not working the way I think it should

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the `isTruthy()` function works.

In the below MWE, inputs into the first matrix are summed and plotted straight-line over 10 periods. However this works ONLY IF the matrix 2 creation function is commented-out like in this MWE. When matrix 2 creation is un-commented (matrix 2 does the same thing as matrix 1: inputs are summed and plotted, but plotted as a separate line), matrix 1 inputs are no longer summed and plotted.

The issue appears to lie in `if(isTruthy(input$matrix2)){...` under the  `plotData <- reactive({...}` function in the `server` section. I thought `if(isTruthy(...)` in this context meant if there are manual inputs into matrix 2, then plot matrix 2, otherwise skip ahead to the `else{...}` and just plot matrix 1. (Note that in the larger App this code is derived from, matrix 2 is rendered in modal dialog, thus the reason why plotting has been broken up this way).

How would I change this code so that matrix 2 is only plotted if there are manual inputs into matrix 2; otherwise plot matrix 1? In order to solve a larger problem I have, I'd like matrix 1 to plot correctly even when matrix 2 is present.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

sumMat <- function(x){return(rep(sum(x,na.rm = TRUE), 10))}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      matrixInput("matrix1",
                  value = matrix(c(60,5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
                  rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE), class = "numeric"),
      # matrixInput("matrix2",
      #             label = "Matrix 2 (Value Y applied in Period X):",
      #             value = matrix(c(60,5),ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,rep("Scenario 1",2))),
      #             rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
      #             cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
      #             class = "numeric"),
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))  
  )    
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    tmpMat1 <- input$matrix1
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix1) == "")){rownames(tmpMat1) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix1)))}
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat1)
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      if(isTruthy(input$matrix2)){
        lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix2)/2), 
               function(i){
                 tibble(Scenario = colnames(input$matrix2)[i*2-1],
                        X = seq_len(10),Y = sumMat(input$matrix2[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE]))
               }) %>% bind_rows()
      } else
        {tibble(Scenario = "Scenario 1", X = seq_len(10),Y = sumMat(input$matrix1))},
      error = function(e) NULL)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/shiny/html/isTruthy.html) help?  What value does `input$matrix2` contain before the user inputs any values for it?  Is this value one of those listed in the link I provided?  If not, then change your code to test for the value of the "empty" `input$matrix2 rather than using `isTruthy`.

Comment: Very helpful. I was misinterpreting how isTruthy() works. Most salient points are:  "...a value is truthy unless it is one of: FALSE, NULL,"", An empty atomic vector, An atomic vector that contains only missing values, A logical vector that contains all FALSE or missing values, An object of class "try-error", A value that represents an unclicked actionButton()". So I removed isTruthy(). However my errors in the original code posted are compounded by flawed if/then/else logic under plotData() in server section. It is now all corrected in the answer I'm about to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See error explanation in CuriousJorge response to Limey comment (incorrect use of `isTruthy()`, flawed if/then/else logic in the `plotData()` function).

Note how matrix 1 inputs "downstream" to matrix 2 as scenario 1.

Below is the resolved code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

sumMat <- function(x){return(rep(sum(x,na.rm = TRUE), 10))}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      matrixInput("matrix1",
                  label ="Matrix 1 (scenario 1):",
                  value = matrix(c(60,5), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
                  rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                  class = "numeric"),
      matrixInput("matrix2",
                  label = "Matrix 2:",
                  value = matrix(c(60,5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
                  rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                  cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
                  class = "numeric")
      ),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    a <- apply(input$matrix2,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix2),nrow(input$matrix1)))
    b <- apply(input$matrix1,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix2),nrow(input$matrix1)))
    c <- if(length(a) == 2){c(b)} else {c(b,a[,-1:-2])}
    d <- ncol(input$matrix2)
    tmpMat2 <- matrix(c(c), ncol = d)
    colnames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat2),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat2)))

    if(any(rownames(input$matrix1) == "")){
      tmpMat1 <- input$matrix1
      rownames(tmpMat1) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix1)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat1)
      }
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
      colnames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat2),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat2)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
      }
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
      }
    input$matrix2
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix2)/2), 
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix2)[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(10),
                 Y = sumMat(input$matrix2[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```